# regression map vs correlation map

Tags: atmosphere, climate, oceanography, statistics, mathematics

What is the exact difference between regression and correlation maps?

I know that they are often used in climate science but which is the difference in the information they provide? Here an example I found online:

[image]

Is the regression map between two quantities $A(t)$ and $B(x,y,t)$, the map of the following index:

$$r = \frac{corr( A(t), B(x,y,t) )}{var( A(t) )}$$

while the correlation simply the map of

$$corr(A(t), B(x,y,t))$$ ?

Comment: From the units given, it appears that the Correlation map shows the r values while the Regression map shows the standard deviation of the correlation, so roughly the spread in the data. Seems backwards to me.